# Continuity and integrability;is it true?

Tags: integration, continuity

If we have a discontinuous real function of all nonnegative terms and $\int^b_a fdx=0$, then does that necessarily imply $f(x)=0$?
I can't come up with an example to help me understand.

Comment: $f=0$ "almost surely", or actually identically zero? The latter is false: look at the function which is only 1 on rational numbers, and 0 everywhere else.

Comment: what does "almost surely" mean?

Comment: $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, except on a set of measure 0 (e.g., a finite or countable number of points). Yes, the integral of the function I mention earlier will be zero.

Comment: yes actually that must be true--because $ f $ is still integrable (it's discontinuous but integrable)

Comment: $f$ is integrable in what sense?

Comment: In the sense that the upper and lower integrals are equal

Answer (score 1):

No, it's false, even with the Riemann integral because you can change the values of $f(x)$ at a finite number of points, this won't change the value of the integral. For instance, take $f(x)=0$ on $[0,1]$, except at $\frac kn\enspace (0\le k\le n$: $f\Bigl(\frac kn\Bigr)=1$. Then $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x=0$.

Actually, with the Lebesgue integral, one shows that if the integral is $0$ and $f(x)\ge 0$, then $f(x)=0\,$ *almost everywhere*, i.e. everywhere except possible on a subset of measure $0$. Any denumerable subset has measure $0$, but a subset of measure $0$ can be very complicated.

Comment: You could even do it with an infinite number of points with the Riemann integral, I think they just can't have an accumulation point.

Comment: I wanted to stay as simple as possible. That's why I only  mention the notion of a set of measure $0$.

Comment: For sure, I was just adding information for OP's purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider 
$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1.8 \text{ if }  x=0\\
0 \text{ if } x\neq 0
\end{cases}$

Then $\int f(x)\mathop{dx}=0$ but $f\neq 0$.